# Variance of an ARIMA forecast

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, arima

Suppose I have an $ARIMA(p,d,q)$ model:

$ \left(1 - \sum_{i=1}^p \alpha_i B^i \right) \nabla^d X_n =  \left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^q \beta_i B^i\right)\epsilon_n$

where $B$ is the shift operator (or lag operator), $\nabla$ is the backward difference operator and $\{\epsilon_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is a white noise process.

Further, suppose I have observed values $x_0, x_1 , \ldots, x_m$, with $m > \max(p+d, q)$.

I want to estimate a future value $\hat x_j$, where $j > m$, using Box-Jenkins.

Is there, in general, a closed-form expression for the variance of the estimator $\hat X_j$?

*(Not homework. I'm asking this because [another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60176/predicting-the-year-computers-will-be-able-to-do-1-exaflops-using-historical-dat) might benefit from this one being answered.)*

Answer (score 1):

The best answer for this is to review W.S. Wei's text on forecasting entitled [Time Series Analysis](http://ruangbacafmipa.staff.ub.ac.id/files/2012/02/Time-Series-Analysis-by.-Wei.pdf) (version 2) . Section 16.7.4 details the precise equations for forecasting. He refers to [AUTOBOX](http://www.autobox.com), software that I have helped to write, as a preferred tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but a reference on its own really isn't an answer. (Unless, of course, my question was so broad as to require a whole book to answer -- in which case I'd appreciate it if you said so directly).

Comment: You don't need the entire book BUT you can get the section from http://ruangbacafmipa.staff.ub.ac.id/files/2012/02/Time-Series-Analysis-by.-Wei.pdf. There is no need for me to duplicate what is already available.

Comment: I didn't expect I'd have to quote chapter-and-verse to a high-karma user, but... [SE guidelines disagree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). So does the "[How to Answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer)" page on CV. But thanks for the reference, I'll make sure to look into it.

Comment: @IrishStat Thanks for including the link to Wei's text. An excellent book that will be useful to anyone who visits this question looking to find out about ARIMA forecasts.